# Как хранить иерархичные данные в списке

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс. Данные я получаю из Excel файла, пробегаясь по разным листам. Данные есть - теперь надо понять - как построить из них иерархию. Как вообще можно хранить иерархичные данные в списке?

```
public class DB
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос на en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541761/best-c-sharp-collection-for-hierarchical-data-storage

Comment: Не храните в списке, храните в иерархической структуре

Comment: Ну и решение, вероятно, будет зависеть от того, что вам потом с этими данными надо делать

Comment: @АндрейNOP посчитать количество родителей, просто пробежаться по списку

Comment: Ну для второй задачи подойдет обход в ширину/глубину, либо хранить отдельно дерево (лес) и отдельно плоский список, в этом тоже ничего плохого (но будут нюансы при модификации элементов, некоторые моменты нужно будет синхронизировать)

Comment: С другой стороны, даже хранение в словаре позволит посчитать количество родителей (если вы под этим понимаете глубину вложенности): `while (current != null) { count++; current = dict[current.ParentId]; }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP есть идеи?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Какого рода иерархия Вам нужна? Какие операции над элементами Вам нужно реализвать? Какие из них должны быть наиболее эффективны?

Comment: Идеи чего? Я же вам все расписал уже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим есть класс

```
public class DB
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Мы можем хранить его в словаре

```
Dictionary<string, DB> store = new Dictionary<string, DB> ();
```

Заполним словарь рандомно

```
var r = new Random();   
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    var db = new DB {
    Code = $"code {i}",
        Id = i.ToString(),
        Name = $"name {i}",
        ParentId = i %  (r.Next(99)+1) == 0 ? null : r.Next(100).ToString()
    };

    store.Add(db.Id, db);       
}
```

Поиск родителей - тривиальное занятие

```
public int GetCountOfParents(Dictionary<string, DB> store, string id)
{
    var parents = new HashSet<string>();
    var q = new Queue<string>();    
    q.Enqueue(id);  
    while(q.Count>0)
    {
        var item = q.Dequeue();
        var parent = store[item].ParentId;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) && parents.Add(parent)) q.Enqueue(parent);
    }   
    return parents.Count;
}
```

Пробежаться по всем элементам еще проще

```
foreach (var item in store.Values)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id} has {GetCountOfParents(store, item.Id)} parents");
```

Вывод закономерен

```
0 has 0 parents
1 has 1 parents
2 has 11 parents
3 has 0 parents
4 has 5 parents
5 has 1 parents
.....
91 has 10 parents
92 has 5 parents
93 has 4 parents
94 has 8 parents
95 has 8 parents
96 has 5 parents
97 has 10 parents
98 has 11 parents
99 has 9 parents
```

Если интересны прямо переходы между парентами, можно добавить вот такую функцию

```
public IEnumerable<DB> GetParents(Dictionary<string, DB> store, string id)
{
    var parents = new HashSet<string>();
    var q = new Queue<string>();
    q.Enqueue(id);
    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = q.Dequeue();
        var parent = store[item].ParentId;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) && parents.Add(parent))
        {
            yield return store[parent];
            q.Enqueue(parent);
        }
    }   
}
```

Перечислить все вот так

```
foreach (var item in store.Values)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id} has parents {GetParents(store, item.Id).Aggregate("", (x, y) => $"{x} => {y.Id}")} ");
```

На выходе получим

```
0 has parents  
1 has parents  => 27 => 77 => 19 => 48 => 72 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58 
2 has parents  => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58 
3 has parents => 69 => 54 => 44 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
4 has parents => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
5 has parents => 57 => 99 => 4 => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
6 has parents => 62 => 5 => 57 => 99 => 4 => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
7 has parents => 54 => 44 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
8 has parents => 13 => 41 => 68 => 37 => 89 => 1 => 27 => 77 => 19 => 48 => 72 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
9 has parents => 69 => 54 => 44 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
10 has parents => 32 => 6 => 62 => 5 => 57 => 99 => 4 => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
11 has parents => 56
.......
91 has parents => 82 => 22 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
92 has parents => 41 => 68 => 37 => 89 => 1 => 27 => 77 => 19 => 48 => 72 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
93 has parents => 84 => 44 => 2 => 85 => 71 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
94 has parents
95 has parents => 58
96 has parents => 6 => 62 => 5 => 57 => 99 => 4 => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
97 has parents => 43 => 46
98 has parents => 65 => 59 => 30 => 95 => 58
99 has parents => 4 => 12 => 39 => 75 => 49 => 14 => 86 => 67 => 61
```

Ну и имейте ввиду, что я при генерации совсем не следил за ацикличностью.

**UPD**

Более простая версия для получения родителей, даже очереди не надо

```
public IEnumerable<DB> GetParents(Dictionary<string, DB> store, string id)
{
    var parents = new HashSet<string>();    
    id = store[id].ParentId;

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && parents.Add(id))
    {       
        yield return store[id];
        id = store[id].ParentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: изумительно!!!!!

Comment: @Radzhab добавил версию без очереди, хотя по скорости работы и старые версии сойдут.

Comment: А зачем HashSet? Чтобы избежать циклы?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага.